# C# Using a variable in multiple classes

Tags: c#

My question is if there is any way for an internal class variable public so that it could be used in multiple classes?

Example: I have a variable called password when the user types a new password. I want to do so this variable can be sent over to my Username class so I can do a summary of them both: Username: HeyIamCool | Password: hello123.

```
using System;

namespace Project{

    public static class Password {

        public static void Main() {

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your new password");

            string password = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Are you sure you want to change your password to: " + password + "? (Yes/No)");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            if(input.ToLower() == "yes") 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your password has been changed to " + password + "!");
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue..");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.Clear();
                Username.Name ();

            }
            else if(input.ToLower() == "no")
            {
            Console.WriteLine(password + " will not be saved as your password");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to restart");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
            Main();
            //System.Environment.Exit(0);

            }

            else 
            {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR! Press any key to restart");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
            Main ();
            }
        }




    }
    public static class Username 
    {
        public static void Name () 
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a username you would like");
        Console.ReadLine();
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "transfer"?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking

Comment: This smells like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/136915), could be better addressed if you tell what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Are you talking about dragging blocks of text in the text editor?

Comment: @DubstepZedd don't post explanations or code samples as comments, [edit] them into your question

Comment: You can expose member variables in lots of different ways (getter methods, `public` properties or even just making the variable itself `public`). What exactly have you tried and where is the problem? Ideally create a [mcve] to showcase your issue

Comment: Before trying to figure out how to program by yourself, you might want to read through the [Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/). For your particular problem probably [Classes and Structs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/index) and [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) and [Accessor Accessibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/restricting-accessor-accessibility).

Comment: @DubstepZedd [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) might help you with posting the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can either set the variable itself to public:

```
public string password = "password";
```

Or you can leave it private and write a getter function for it:

```
private string password = "password";

public string GetPassword()
{
    return password;
}
```

Then when you want to retrieve it you just create an instance of your password class

```
Password pass = new Password();

string myPassword = pass.password;  //if you used a public variable

string myPassword = pass.GetPassword(); //if you used a private variable
```

Comment: You can also make it `private` and use a getter. `public string Password => password;`

Comment: What is positive by even keeping a string private? But I guess it answers my question. I thought strings couldn't contain numbers though so I guess I gotta read a little more lol

Comment: Here's a helpful summary for why private variables are useful [found on stack exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/143736/why-do-we-need-private-variables).

Strings can contain numbers, they just need to be surrounded by quotes. For example:

string five = "5";

Comment: But a string can't be "hey0.5" though? Because that isnt an integer right?

Comment: A string can be whatever you want to put inside those quotes. "hey0.5" is a valid string.

The only time you might run into trouble is trying to use \ or " inside of a string. This can be done by prepending that character with \.

So \\ or \"

For more information you can look up string escape characters

Comment: @emsimpson92 I tried your solution. I got 76 problems when I wrote public string password. Any ideas?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing the details of the errors. Can you share your code so I can take a look at it?

After reading the updated problem description it might be easier to create a class called user and have private variables for both username, password, name, age, and whatever else you might need. Unless there is some specific reason you want to keep the classes separate?

Comment: @emsimpson92 here is the code without any changes to it. (without the errors). I  had some trouble pasting it in btw

Comment: What sort of errors are you getting? The only thing I see at first glance is you didn't declare an instance of your username class. You can't just say Username.Name(), you have to do something like this: `Username user = new Username();

user.Name();
`

Answer (score 0):

While we can't provide a definitive answer by your question, we can access member variables from outside its class by using reflection:

```
public class Example
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var target = new Mistery();
        foreach (var field in target.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | 
                                                         BindingFlags.NonPublic))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", field.Name, field.GetValue(target));
        }
    }
}

public class Mistery
{
    private string _secret = "hello123";
}
```

You could be also talking about inheritance, where you can define some members in a `base` class and use them in `derivate` classes.

```
public class MyBase
{
    protected string Secret = "hello123";
}

public class MyDerived : MyBase
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Secret);  // Will write the secret variable value
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's complicated, well I thought a string couldnt have numbers so yeah that was the issue

Comment: So this can be helpful: [C# Types and variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/types-and-variables)

Comment: Or a better c# data types tutorial

Comment: Yeah that second link was good, better explanations. Is there a way to give someone a thumbs up on this site?